# How can We log javascript functions in asp.net web application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on asp.net web application and I'm using javascript in my code to handle client side actions.

As I'm new to javascript I don't know how to use logging in javascript code. 
Whenever I face any client side issue, I need to use firbug in firefox. so If is there any library or some javascript inbuilt functions to enable logging please let me know so that It will be easy for me to debug my application.

Comment: What's wrong with Firebug in Firefox? It's one of the best javascript debugging tools available. Or you need logging and auditing of your javascript application when deployed?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `debugger;` tag inside you'r java-script code.
so when this code is running and the debugging is allowed in you'r browser you can debug the code in Visual Studio.

to enable debugging on IE and other browser just uncheck the highlighted lines [image]

Comment: How can be debug javascript functions using visual studio?

Comment: yea this is right. it is good stuff. but i prefer usually using chrome dev tool for debugging client side.